# Unhandled microsoft c++ exception cv exception at memory location

Tags: c++, opencv, exception

I currently developped a project with VS and OpenCV on my x64 computer and i've a problem with this line:

```
model->train(image, labels);
```

image and labels are not empty but i've got this error:

> Unhandled exception at at 0x774FC42D in facerec_video.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0015EF38.

If i click "continue", program continue and works.
Furthermore, if i set a breakpoint on this line and do a step by step, error message doesn't appear and program works too.

How to resolve this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: usually that's because you're mixing debug and release OpenCV libs, or x86 and x64, or VS compiler (vc11 and vc12 usually)

Comment: Sure, i have debug and release libs
I have this error message in debug, but i've only linked in the additional dependencies the "lib_d.lib" format